# how to get twitter summary card with Tweepy

Tags: twitter, tweepy

I wonder how to get the summary card (shown below) using Tweepy?

Thanks.
Dan

the summary card is shown in the circle

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

The [Twitter Card](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/cards/overview/abouts-cards) is generated by Twitter when a Tweet (or a Direct Message) includes a URL.
Using Tweepy you can get the content of the Tweet including the URL, in both the t.co form (used by Twitter) and the original one:

```
'urls': [{'url': 'twitter tiny url', 'expanded_url': 'https://www.example.com',
```

In order to be able to generate the Twitter Card preview the web page must include specific META tag

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@beppecatanese" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="My GitHub space" />
<meta name="twitter:description" content="View my GitHub space." />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://github.com/gcatanese" />
```

The Twitter Card is not always correctly generated, I am explaining this [here](https://medium.com/@beppe.catanese/tweesky-dont-miss-the-twitter-card-preview-19c95f3417d9) if you are interested

Comment: Thanks. Beppe! So I have to get the information from the original URL instead of the tweet, is that right?

Comment: The tweet url will redirect to the original one anyway, but yes it is the original URL the one you need